# Odd behavior with urlparse

Tags: python, url, urlparse

I was wondering if there are known workarounds to some odd behavior I'm seeing with python's urlparse.

Here are some results from a couple of lines in the python interpeter:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qsl('https://localhost/?code=bork&charlie=brown')
[('https://localhost/?code', 'bork'), ('charlie', 'brown')]
```

In the above example, why is the key for the first value 'https://localhost/?code'?  Shouldn't it just be 'code'? Note: parse_qs has the same bad behavior.

```
>>> urlparse.urlparse('abcd://location/?code=bork&charlie=brown')
ParseResult(scheme='abcd', netloc='location', path='/?code=bork&charlie=brown', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse.urlparse('https://location/?code=bork&charlie=brown')
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='location', path='/', params='', query='code=bork&charlie=brown', fragment='')
```

In the above example note that the query string doesn't always get put into the query value. Why does the protocol matter at all?  Shouldn't the query field always get the query string? Testing with 'ftp' or other well known protocols seems to also be unhappy.

Comment: Are GET parameters used outside of HTTP? I think `?foo=bar` only means something if you're dealing with HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`urlparse.parse_qsl`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) (and [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)) are methods intended for the query part of the request (the string after the `?`).

Maybe you want to use a method that understands whole URLs first ([`urlparse.urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse)), and then pass the query from the result to `urlparse_qsl`:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> myurl = urlparse.urlparse('https://localhost/?code=bork&charlie=brown')
>>> print myurl
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='localhost', path='/', params='', query='code=bork&charlie=brown', fragment='')
>>> print myurl.scheme
https
>>> print urlparse.parse_qs(myurl.query)
{'charlie': ['brown'], 'code': ['bork']}
```

The scheme matters, because although the query exists in the generic syntax, some protocols may not support them.

**See also:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme (check out the official registered schemes)

Comment: I see.  Thanks for linking the reference.  My understanding of URI's was somewhat flawed.

Comment: I was looking at the example from the wikipedia article that you linked. In their example of 'foo://username:password@example.com:8042/over/there/index.dtb?type=animal&name=narwhal#nose' it still seemed like everything after the '?' was considered the query. Given that I'd expect to be able to pass 'foo://blah/?cat=leo&dog=charlie' to urlparse and get 'cat=leo&dog=charlie' back. That however isn't the case. Am I wrong to generally expect that?

Comment: Again, thanks for explaining.  I was wondering if you knew of a way to specify a new scheme for urlparse to use.  Basically I'd want to be able to say to urlparse "hey, treat my new scheme foo just like https except the scheme name is different".  Or even be able to define some arbitrary rules for a new scheme to urlparse... maybe that isn;t possible and the way to go is to just use regex.

Comment: Appending my scheme name urlparse.uses_query (and some other uses_* things) totally fixes this. I guess adding your custom scheme to each generic known bit is a way to customize. Cool once you know that is available.

Comment: sorry, man, it was way past my bedtime when I wrote this, I didn't get to see your questions in time. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) (and `parse_qsl`) do state that it's meant to "Parse a query string given as a string argument." You're not giving it a query string, you're giving it the whole URL. Try this instead:

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qsl('code=bork&charlie=brown')
[('code', 'bork'), ('charlie', 'brown')]
```